# Deeper levels of (sub)sections don't appear in the LaTeX output of pandoc. Why?

Tags: sectioning, pandoc, markdown

I use [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) to create latex and PDF from Markdown. Markdown, being designed for HTML, allows 6 levels of headers H1...H6. But when converting to PDF, via tex, I get only three levels: 1 (`\section`), 1.1 (`\subsection`) and 1.1.1 (`\subsubsection`).

The tex source has no command around the deeper level headers. 1.1.1.1 simply does not exist and is treated as plain text.

Where should I look, in order to get latex to support deeper levels of headers/sections? Is that possible at all? Or should I consider restructuring the document so as never to go below 1.1.1, header level three, `\subsubsection`?

Comment: Some good answers here already. For a broader, fairly comprehensive look at the TeX document hierarchy, check out http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure

Comment: I have the same problem: I expected that in the output from pandoc the headers of level 4 or 5 would become `\paragraph`, but they are just plain text. Have you found a fix for this?

Comment: (Neither of the answers below doesn't seem to answer the question about making pandoc generate `\paragraph`. I wonder why it is accepted then...)

Comment: Imz, the answers at that time were in lines of "not possible, restructure your document". Mostly answering to my ignorance about levels in `TeX`. Which is a crude solution, but a solution nonetheless. Yours is indeed a better solution and should probably become the accepted answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably, newer versions of pandoc fix this problem. I've just run my simple example:

```
# Section
## Subsection
### Subsubsection
#### Paragraph
##### Subparagraph
###### Level 6
```

[through Try Pandoc online!](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try/?text=%23+Section%0A%23%23+Subsection%0A%23%23%23+Subsubsection%0A%23%23%23%23+Paragraph%0A%23%23%23%23%23+Subparagraph%0A%23%23%23%23%23%23+Level+6%0A&from=markdown&to=latex), and the output **does use** `\paragraph`:

```
\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

\paragraph{Paragraph}

\subparagraph{Subparagraph}

Level 6
```

It has been done with pandoc 1.11.1, whereas my installed older pandoc-1.6.0.1 produced:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage[mathletters]{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[breaklinks=true,unicode=true]{hyperref}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}


\begin{document}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

Paragraph

Subparagraph

Level 6

\end{document}
```

without `\paragraph`.

(`pandoc` vs `pandoc --standalone` make no difference as to this issue.)

Comment: An answer is much better ;-)

Comment: Subparagraph being the deepest LaTeX level (as jgm elucidated [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1480)).

Answer (score 19):

```
\documentclass{report}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\begin{document}
\part{Part}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\paragraph{Paragraph}
\subparagraph{Subparagraph}
\end{document}
```

You can change the formatting of these using the `titlesec` package.

Answer (score 12):

There are two levels below `\subsubsection` which are `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph`.
Whether some sectioning command is numbered or appears in the table of contents is selected by the `secnumdepth` and `tocdepth` counters, respectively.