# How to show subsubsections and paragraphs in table of content

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents

I have a table of content that shows the chapters, section and subsections. However, I want to list the subsubsections and paragraphs too.

In the document all of them are listed (enumerated) but for some unknown reason they are not displayed in the table of content.

I have set the counters:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}   
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
```

I don't have anything else that explicitly tells to LaTeX to display the chapters, section, etc. in the table of content.

The current result is something like:

> Chapter
>   ...Section
>   ......Subsection

The expected result would be:

> Chapter
>   ..Section
>   ....Subsection
>   ......Subsubsection
>   ........Paragraph

Sorry for my ugly list :P

I'm using the following packages:

```
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelfont=bf,it]{caption}
\geometry{top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=3.0cm, right=2.5cm}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{cmr} % Roman
\renewcommand{\encodingdefault}{T1}
\newcommand{\subscript}[1]{\ensuremath{_{\textrm{#1}}}}
\setstretch{1.5}
```

Comment: Can you post a MWE for this?

Comment: Try posting a minimal working example, or at least tell us which document class / packages you use. [This page](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=916) has a working example showing exactly what you want to do, so you can seek inspiration here.

Comment: Are you loading any other packages? You mention that "all of them are listed...but...they are not displayed in the table of content[s]" while later you mention "the current result" which shows a ToC. Please provide more detail in terms of your current setup, preferably via a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that clearly illustrates your problem.

Comment: @TimothéePoisot Thank you for the advice, I converted it to a comment, since it's not really an answer or solution, respectively.

Comment: If I put your preamble in a `book` documentclass and comment out the `fmtcount` (simply because I don't have it on my system and I can't imagine it would cause this) it works fine, everything up to the paragraph is shown in the table of contents. Are you perhaps using a different documentclass? A non-standard one?

Comment: Are you using the starred commands for subsubsections (`\subsubsection*`) because they don’˝ generate a ToC entry …

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deeper levels of (sub)sections](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17780/deeper-levels-of-subsections)

Comment: I have that question too and dislike to see answers barred by its closure.